# How to Trim Non English characters

Tags: c#, .net

I've a string with Spanish language and I need to remove some characters '[', ']' etc,. from it. If i use `str.Trim('p', 'P', '[', ']')` it is not doing the work. Can someone help me?

```
stirng str="¿Quiere poner en blanco la pantalla? Presione 1 para la pantalla en blanco, presione 2 para mantener la pantalla. Para cancelar esta operación, presione la tecla cancelar [P200] Presione la tecla inferior derecha para ajustar el volumen [P200] Para repetir las instrucciones, presione la tecla inferior izquierda en el teclado"
```

Comment: `String.Trim` - *Returns a new string in which all **leading and trailing** occurrences of a set of specified characters from the current string are removed.* What about replace with empty string?

Comment: `Trim()` only removes characters at the beginning or end of the string. Are you looking for `Replace()`?

Comment: "non English" is way too vague and probably includes characters found in English names, eg `Charlotte Brontë` or `naïve`. The only unusual character in that string is `¿`. `[` and `]` are found in English phrases

Comment: I doubt that you will want to change "poner" into "oner" by removing all "p"s

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question to make it more clear what you want. The example is presumably misleading. Could it be that you want to remove the `[P200]` part as that isn't a "word" in a natural language?

Comment: You can use a regular expression to match and remove classes or groups of characters. `¿` is part of both [Latin-1 and the Unicode Common block](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm) though. It's part of the [Latin-1 Supplement](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/utf8test.htm) block that includes, eg © and ÷. It's in the [Punctuation Other (Po)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Po/list.htm) category that includes both the Comma (,) and the Full Stop (.). There's nothing specific to Spanish even for `¿`

Comment: In string "A [P200] B" do you want to remove just '[', 'P', ']', so that the result becomes "A 200 B", or do you want to remove everything between the brackets, and the brackets, so that the result becomes "A B"?

Comment: If you want to remove specific characters you can use `Regex.Replace`, eg `Regex.Replace(input,"[pP\[\]]","");` [Brackets are part of the `Punctuation, Open (Ps)` and `Punctuation, Close (Pe)` category, so you can probably use `[\{Ps}\{Pe}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace `[P200]` with `200`, you can use a Regular Expression to match that pattern specifically and extract the number. `\[P(?<num>\d+)\]` will match `[P123]` and capture the number in the `num` named group:

```
var regex=new Regex(@"\[P(?<num>\d+)\]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var result=regex.Replace(input,"${num}");
```

This produces

> ¿Quiere poner en blanco la pantalla? Presione 1 para la pantalla en blanco, presione 2 para mantener la pantalla. Para cancelar esta operación, presione la tecla cancelar 200 ...

If you want to remove the entire match, use `""` as the replacement value. The named group isn't needed any more though, so the regular expression can be simplified to `\[P\d+\]` :

```
var regex=new Regex(@"\[P\d+\]",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result=regex.Replace(input,"");
```

If you want to remove everything between square brackets, the pattern becomes `\[.+?\]`. Without `?` the pattern would match everything from the first opening bracket to the last closing bracket

Comment: Awesome. Worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

[`String.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-6.0) removes all leading and trailing chars, so at the beginning and end of the string, not between. You could use this extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveAll(this string s, params char[] removeChars)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
        foreach (char c in s)
            if (!removeChars.Contains(c))
                sb.Append(c);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

```
str = str.RemoveAll('p', 'P', '[', ']');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All! I've found solution for my Requirement.

```
public static string RemoveBetween(string sourceString, string startTag, string endTag)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", Regex.Escape(startTag), Regex.Escape(endTag)), RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
        return regex.Replace(sourceString, startTag + endTag);
    }

string str = "BienvenidoalcajeroconinstruccionesaudiblesdeNCRBank.[p300]Estecajeroledaráinstruccionesparasuusopormediodelaudífono.[P300]Estecajeroproveeinstruccionesaudiblesqueleayudaránaejecutartransacciones.Eltecladoqueustedvaausarparahacersusseleccionesenelusodelcajeroestasituadoaunaalturaaproximadade3piesdelpiso.Lasteclasestanordenadasenformasimilaraladeunteléfonoconunafilamasdeteclasaladerechadelteclado.Ustedpuedeempezarsutransacciónencualquiermomentoinsertandosutarjetaenellectordetarjetasubicandolaescrituraenrelievedelatarjetahaciaarribayhacialaizquierda.";
string test = RemoveBetween(str, "[", "]"); //convert [p300] -> [];
var removeList = new string[] { "[", "]" };
removeList.ToList().ForEach(o => test = test.Replace(o, "")); // Will remove []
```

Comment: What *is* the requirement? Remove `[p300]` entirely? Replace it with `300`? You can do either in a single line.

Comment: I want to remove [p300]

Comment: In that case match `\[P\d+?\]` and replace it with `""`. I posted various options in my answer